# Do I need companions to follow me for the companion perks to work?

Tags: fallout-4

Will the companion perks still work if they are not following me or if I'm with different companions?

Comment: The fallout tag isn't a catch-all for the entire series - it's specifically for the game *Fallout*, so unless you're asking about **both** Fallout 4 and Fallout, it doesn't belong on this question.